MariaDB connection failed using Java in Android Studio
I'm trying to connect my android (java) application to a MariaDB Database I have in localhost with docker.
I don't have a lot of experience programming, so any help is appreciated with this error ^^-
When I launch the app into the emulator/physical device it never connects to that database:
Connection fail
Here's the code:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
                Connection c = dbManager.getconnection();
                if(c != null){
                    Log.e("Test_a", "Connection established");
                }else{
                    Log.e("Test_a", "Conenction failed");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

public class DatabaseManager {
    private final String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/molds";
    private final String usr = "-";
    private final String psw = "s";

    public Connection getconnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, psw);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}

However, I coded an another app in NetBeans (I was testing) and it connected with no problems with the same code:
Test worked
public class Asd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/molds", "root", "secret");
            
            if(con != null){
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Connection failed");
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}

I have implementated the MariaDB jdbc:
implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.3.3")
I don't know why it is not working. Also I know this is not recommended, but i'm just testing (learning). Appreciate help.
